# How to export the files under a label from TFS in a script using tf?

Tags: version-control, tfs, tf-cli

I need a batch script that uses tf to retrieve the directory structure for a label in TFS, something like the equivalent of svn export, while not messing up with my current working workspace.

This is what I managed to come up with:

```
tf workspace /new TemporaryWorkspace /noprompt
```

This will create a new workspace, but with the following working folder:
 $/: C:\ 
(considering that I ran the command from C:)

This is not what I want, but "tf workspace /new" doesn't seem to allow specifying the mapping, so I ran this to remove the default mapping:

```
tf workfold /unmap $/ /workspace:TemporaryWorkspace
```

then this one to create my desired mapping.

```
tf workfold /workspace:TemporaryWorkspace /map $/Project/Path C:\Temp\Path
```

Change the current directory to the local working folder (I don't know of another way to select the current workspace)

```
PUSHD C:\Temp\Path
```

Now I can finally retrieve the label and do my stuff with it.

```
tf get /version:LMyBeautifulLabel
```

Now the clean up.

```
tf workspace /delete TemporaryWorkspace /noprompt
```

Go back

```
POPD
```

All these seems a bit too cumbersome for my humble purpose. Is there a simpler way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will need to create a workspace with the proper working folder mappings and then run the `get`.  There's no one-liner alias to set this up for you.

You may be able to get by with creating a longer-lived workspace with the proper working folder mappings that you need not delete, but certainly if you're using this workflow frequently but with different labels or in different locations, creating a new temporary workspace each time probably does make the most sense.

Your best solution here is to either create a command script that executes this workflow or use the little known script functionality of the `tf` command line client.  You can run a `tf` script by using:

```
tf @<filename>
```

or simply using:

```
tf @
```

to read from standard input.